# How to Restrict someone from putting an Autosys Job On Ice

Tags: unix, jobs, autosys

I am facing a scenario where i have an autosys Job A. And jobs B, C, D are dependent on A.
When we keep the job A On Ice, B,C,D fail.

We had multiple incidents where A was kept on ice by mistake.

**Is there any way that we can restrict the job A from being put On Ice?**

I desperately need to avoid such incidents from happening in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the permission attribute of the job to restrict who can edit and execute a job. Default permission is that only owner can edit and execute the job. In this case I think the user has logged into the Autosys session using the job's 'owner' credentials, and hence that person would be able to change the job's status. Solution would be to irradicate the need to put the job on ice as suggested by friends above.

OR If the user id is different, check the permission attribute in the job definition, and remove the entry.
Valid values are:
gx
(UNIX only) Assigns group execute permissions to the job.
ge
(UNIX only) Assigns group edit permissions to the job.
me
Indicates that any authorized user may edit the job, regardless of the machine they are on. Otherwise, the user must be logged on to the machine specified in the owner field (for example, user@host_or_domain).
mx
Indicates that any authorized user may execute the job, regardless of the machine they are on. Otherwise, the user must be logged on to the machine specified in the owner field (for example, user@host_or_domain).
we
Assigns world edit permissions to the job.
wx
Assigns world execute permissions to the job.
The job's owner always has full edit and execute permissions.
Example: Set Permissions to Execute and Edit a Job on UNIX
This example sets permissions on UNIX so that any user can execute the job, but only members of your group can edit it:
permission: ge, wx

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to be able to do ? Is the point of this to (1) be able to occasionally stop JobA running but also (2) avoid the situation where you forget to re-enable JobA? And do you also need to prevent jobs B/C/D running without jobA running immediately beforehand.

If so then I'd suggest:

1. you don't put jobA on ice. instead add a condition on JobA on the value of an autosys variable that you set to Y when you want to "pause" the job
   eg
   condition: v(var_disable_jobA) !="Y"

   I prefer the negative (!=) check because only setting the value to Y will cause the job to stop running. Using a variable also keeps any dependant jobs paused too, assuming thats what you want.
2. you create a dummy "reminder" job that always fails when it runs (I'm assuming you have some sort of monitoring in place to spot this and consolidate multiple reminders) and make that dependant on the variable too - so that it only runs/fails periodically when JobA is disabled, ie specifies
   insert_job: JobA_disabled
   command: false
   condition: v(var_disable_jobA) = "Y"
   date_conditions: 1
   start_mins: 59,29
   days_of_week: all
   alarm_if_fail: 1
   (apologies if I've put any typos in the JIL)

This way you'll be reminded every 30 mins (but choose your own reminder times) while JobA is disabled. I'd also call the reminder job "JobA_disabled" for clarity. When the variable is to set something other than Y JobA would resume running and the failing reminder job would stop reminding you.

Answer (score 0):

The previous suggestion is a good one. I have one other to add -- what about adding another job, call it job Z. Make B,C and D depend on success of A and success of Z (you can further constrain these by using a lookback). Make Z a short script that runs and only goes to success state of A is not on ice.

This should work but the global variable trick above is good too.  If you're using AutoSys R11.3.n you can probably use a resource that is set at the start of the stream and only released if the job is not on ice or something similar.